# Walking Forward in Google Tour Creator

Tags: video, video-editor, 3d

To start with, I am an amateur when it comes to computational photography. I am trying to use Google's Tour Creator to create a virtual tour of my store. It works perfectly when I am standing at a point and rotating 360 on it. But I want to create a tour where I am walking straight. Imagine a camera mounted on a cart moving through an aisle in a super-market.

Is there some way I can accomplish this? Some other website? Can I code something for this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to simply shoot a video of it. Alternatively, you can use photography from inside the store to generate a photogrammetry model. Simply put, a program looks at a lot of images and stitches them together to a textured 3d-model. You could then walk through the 3d-space. Since you said that you are an amateur at this field, I would highly recommend just filming the motion, or hiring someone who does. All you'd need is a steadicam and a camera, obviously. From 2 or 3 images alone you cannot accomplish such a motion.